# RejectChanges() doesn't undo changes when changes are made on a new entity?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I have a factory with that returns a new entity:

```
//myDataFactory
//some other code here...
function create() {
    return manager.createEntity(entityName);
}
```

In my controller, when ever the backend returns a 404 (not found), I simply trigger that `create()` method when the controller is activated, otherwise I set the object to whatever was returned.

```
        //myDataController
        //some other code here...
        init();

        function init() {
            var promises = [
                getMyData()
            ];

            console.log('populating MyData');
            return q.all(promises).then(function(){
                logger.info('populated MyData.');
            });
        }

        function getMyData() {
            return myDataFactory.getMyData(true).then(
                setMyData,
                createNewMyData
            );
        }

        function setMyData(data) {
            vm.myData = data[0];
        }


        function createNewMyData() {
            vm.myData = myDataFactory.create();
        }
```

In the UI, I have an undo button, that simply calls this function in the myDataController:

```
function undo() {
   vm.myData.entityAspect.rejectChanges();
   vm.termsForm.$setPristine(true);
}
```

The `undo()` function above works really well when there is an object returned from the database. But when I try making changes to a newly created entity which isn't saved yet, when I click undo, it's not going back to it's original value. Why? How do I resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. :D

I am using angularjs with breeze btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Original values" are the values that an **existing** entity had prior to your current, unsaved changes.

A new entity ... one not retrieved from the server and not yet saved ... lacks "original values". It only has "current values". Therefore, `rejectChanges` has nothing to roll back to.

There are other important differences as well. Look at the `thing.entityAspect.entityState.name` of a `thing` entity both *before* and *after* calling `rejectChanges`.

If the state before is "Modified", the state afterward is "Unchanged". But if the state before is "Added", the state afterward is "Detached" ... meaning that the `thing` is no longer in the `EntityManager` cache and is ripe for garbage collection.

With these facts in mind, what would you like the behavior to be? Once you know, we can work out a satisfying plan for your scenario.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Your explanation made it more clearer now! With the create() method above, is there a way for me to have the same effect as undo for unsaved entities? Like for example, if the entity is unsaved yet (as in really brand new- with all the values blank), and the user types in some changes, but decides to hit undo, it will just go back to it's blank brand new state?

Comment: If not, is there a way for me to know if the object is new(unsaved) without making a call in the backend? I could probably just make an if statement that clears the data if the object is new otherwise call rejectChanges().

Comment: My initial thought would be to check if the ID isn't positive number, would that be a reliable enough though?

Comment: Yes, that's reliable enough if you are using an positive-number id generator on the server.

Answer (score 0):

For those stuck, here is my solution based on what I gathered from Mr. Ward's answer. I used [entityState.isAdded()](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/lap-changetracking.html) instead.

```
function undo() {
    if (myDataIsNew()) {
        resetMyData();
    } else {
        vm.myData.entityAspect.rejectChanges();
    }
    setPristineForm();
}

function myDataIsNew() {
    // A new entity in cache that does not exist in the backend database
    return vm.myData.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded();
}

function resetMyData() {
    //clear each property.
}
```